# Change query string parameter in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a component which I need to pass a parameter using query string , once the component is loaded I need to remove the query string from the url. 
My initial url is like `..../#/event/576e9373f835541100cc60b7/info/?case=new`

I just need to remove the query string parameter after some timeout ,

```
 setTimeout(()=> {  
     this.routeParams.set('case','');//seems like there is no set method     
 }, 2000);
```

Any alternatives ?

**Edit**
This route is called from create new screen so that I can show a notification saying creation is successful. If I don't remove the query param from url the notification will show even when user refresh the page.

Comment: You wanna remove query param after loading, why did you pass it clearly, so? You do not need to explicitly pass it, is that what you want? A hidden parameter?

Comment: @LanaStf, See I edited the question

Comment: why don't you show the notification before the redirect? However, this sounds more of a structural problem. An answer to your problem would probably just encourage bad practice. Maybe you can correct me with more information.

Comment: @lexith, Yeah . I kind of sense the same here. But the issue is we need to move user to the next step and notify him that previous step is successful and this is what you can do here. Like "Item is successfully created now you can add more details here !"

Comment: What if you had a piece of code that would be shown only if there is a rootScope var called notification, then you can display whatever you want, wouldn't this work? May you post some more code if it doesn't?

Comment: @JayanthaLalSirisena As i said, you should think about your structure then. Think of a "main" component which holds another component for each of your steps. It should hold all of the information you need (for example an instance of your user model). This parent component should then decide which view to show and pass required informations for example with `@Input` properties.